# rails admin for rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, activeadmin, rails-admin

I have a rails app with dozens of rake tasks defined for admin purpose for now, I want these rake tasks to be reflected on a kind of admin interface, so is there any plug-n-play solution for this or any quick ideas around?

Answer (score 0):

You can get output of `rake -T` and then parse it with regex. i.e. :

```
all_tasks = %x(rake -T)
tasks_array = all_tasks.scan(/(rake\s[\w|:]*)/)
```

`rake -T` is quite long operation, so you may want to cache it